# Spark XML file loading

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I load XML files in Spark 2.0?

```
val rd = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").load("C:/Users/kumar/Desktop/d.xml")
```

I'm getting error com.databricks.spark.xml not available.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.xml. Please find packages at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/Third+Party+Projects
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:148)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:79)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass(DataSource.scala:79)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:325)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:149)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:132)
  ... 48 elided
```

Comment: You apparently didn't include that package on the classpath

Comment: but the rest like com.databicks.spark.csv is working

Answer (score 3):

ClassNotFoundException means that you need a fat jar which you could include the package in your build.sbt and make the jar by sbt assembly. you may have a try.
If can not work. add the jar into $SPARK_HOME/jars and have a try.

Comment: im trying to load in spark shell . how to add jar in shell ?

Comment: refer this [link](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml) spark shell could also work , you put your jar into the $SPARK/jars and --packages optioin could add the xml package ```$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-xml_2.10:0.4.1``` hope this will help

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can add the jar file into your spark shell. Download the [spark-xml_2.10-0.2.0.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/spark-xml_2.10/0.2.0) jar file and copy into the spark's class path and add the jar file in your spark shell using the :cp command as

```
:cp spark-xml_2.10-0.2.0.jar  
/*
  jar file will get imported into the spark shell
  now you can use this jar file anywhere in your code inside the spark shell.
*/
val rd = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").load("C:/Users/kumar/Desktop/d.xml")
```